# Why are relative line numbers useful in Vim?

Tags: line-numbers

I have been used to absolute line numbers (`:set number norelativenumber`). I'm unable to find a good reason and utility value for relative line numbers (`:set nonumber relativenumber`) line or hybrid line numbers (`:set number relativenumber`).

Can someone help me understand their value?

I am sure there is.

Comment: From the documentation: `Relative line numbers help you use the |count| you can precede some vertical motion commands (e.g. j k + -) with, without having to calculate it yourself. Especially useful in combination with other commands (e.g. y d c < > gq gw =)` :h 'relativenumber'

Comment: You may find the following link useful, especially because the gifs help bring relative numbers to life, so to speak. https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/vim-number/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason for relative line number is that some Vim command use relative line number or relative range.

A trivial example is `4j` that moves 4 line down relative to the current line number.

But there are other commands like `:t` or `:m` that copy or move lines that can be used with relative range and relative line numbers.

Move the current line and the next three to start below line 1.

```
:.,+3m1
```

If you want to use such relative ranges and line number it helps to have relative line number shown.

Personally I don't use them very often and I prefer absolute line number too.